# Rscript error using Lenskit / Maven / Eclipse / Mac osx 10.8.4

Tags: eclipse, macos, maven, lenskit

I set up Lenskit, Maven and Eclipse. When testing to see if Lenskit works, I get a "Build Failure" stating the following:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "Rscript": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Does have anybody had the same issue? How to solve it?

Thanks!

---

Solved: Forgot to install R http://www.r-project.org/
Best!

---

Comment: Answer your own question pls, it worked for me too.